# How do I save a file in a Spark PairRDD using the key as the filename and the value as the contents?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

In Spark, I have downloaded multiple files from s3 using sc.binaryFiles. The RDD that results has the key as the filename and the value has the contents of the file. I have decompressed the file contents, csv parsed it, and converted it to a dataframe. So, now I have a PairRDD[String, DataFrame]. The problem I have is that I want to save the file to HDFS using the key as the filename and save the value as a parquet file overwriting one if it already exists. This is what I got so far.

```
val files = sc.binaryFiles(lFiles.mkString(","), 250).mapValues(stream => sc.parallelize(readZipStream(new ZipInputStream(stream.open))))
val tables = files.mapValues(file => {
    val header = file.first.split(",")
    val schema = StructType(header.map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)))
    val lines = file.mapPartitionsWithIndex { (idx, iter) => if (idx == 0) iter.drop(1) else iter }.flatMap(x => x.split("\n"))
    val rowRDD = lines.map(x => Row.fromSeq(x.split(",")))
    sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema)
})
```

If you have any advice, please let me know. I would appreciate it.

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: naive approach : if your keys cardinality are low, you can collect them, iterate on them filter on that key then writing it into disk with the path equal to key.

Answer (score 0):

the way to save files to HDFS in spark is the same to hadoop. So you need to create a class which extends MultipleTextOutputFormat, in custom class you can define output filename yourself.the example is below:

```
class RDDMultipleTextOutputFormat extends MultipleTextOutputFormat[Any, Any] {
    override def generateFileNameForKeyValue(key: Any, value: Any, name: String): String = {
        "realtime-" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm").format(new Date()) + "00-" + name
    }
}
```

the called code is below:

```
RDD.rddToPairRDDFunctions(rdd.map { case (key, list) =>
    (NullWritable.get, key)
}).saveAsHadoopFile(input, classOf[NullWritable], classOf[String], classOf[RDDMultipleTextOutputFormat])
```

Comment: Does this actually work with S3 Native FS without having HDFS ? I'm wondering when the file would actually get uploaded to s3, probably when the job finishes? Because the last X records could belong to all X files... So nothing can be uploaded to s3 before the last record is processed, right ?